# Accessing a guest OS's directory from the host OS in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

With VirtualBox you can share a directory on the host machine with the guest machine.  Can you share a directory on the guest machine with the host machine?  In my setup the host is Windows 7 and the guest is Ubuntu.  Can I have a directory on the Ubuntu file system accesible from Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your VM is a computer in its own right, if you have networking configured correctly you can share a folder through Samba on the Ubuntu box and Windows can then access it via `\\192.168.1.x\SharedFolder`.